# Saving nested fragment sate on back pressed of Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm confused in a fundamental Android fragment lifecycle.

When I press back, none of my nested fragments are saved and the app recreates everything in a parent activity. These nested fragments are inside viewpagers.

Now, if I press the menu button, and come out of the app, it is stored.

Why does it happen? And how do I ensure that even if the user comes out of the app, by pressing back, the nested fragment states are saved, and restored when the user opens the app again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fragment state pager adapter for viewpager's to save the state of fragments. But you can still not change the fragment life cycle which is dependent on activity life cycle. So if an activity's on destroy is called, all its fragments will be destroyed. So, this might be your case.